# Is it possible to use aws s3 commands through Cloudfront?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

We have an application that uses S3 for the object storage. We've discovered a performance issue with S3 because it only uses HTTP/1.1 and image tiles stalling because of the 6 connection limit.

I created a Cloudfront distribution to utilize the HTTP/2 protocol to get around the limitation.  The communication looks to be working.

Our application uses s3 protocol for storing and retrieving objects. When we are using minio for the backend, we can just swap out and use --endpoint-url.  I had assumed it would be similar for Cloudfront, but it isn't working.

The closest I can get to any communication is:

```
aws s3 ls  --endpoint-url https://******.cloudfront.net

'Buckets'
```

Does Cloudfront support S3 or am I going about this all wrong?

Comment: Amazon CloudFront is a completely different service. It does not support S3 API calls. When using CloudFront, objects are still stored in S3, but CloudFront works 'in front' of S3.

Comment: I understand CloudFront is in front of the s3 bucket.  I was hoping it would proxy/work with the s3 api as well and not just straight up HTTP.

Comment: No, CloudFront does not work that way. See: [API Actions - Amazon CloudFront](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/latest/APIReference/API_Operations.html)